# Python how to add __init__ param to subclass

Tags: python, oop

I have a subclass sharing the __ init __ of it's base class:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass)
    def __init__(self, param, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.thing = param
```

The problem I have been having is the subclass __ init __ parameter "param" is being passed into the `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` as an extra parameter. This usually gives me an error like:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I don't want that. I only want "param" to be used for these subclass instances. How do stop sending the extra param to the baseclass __ init __ while still being able to use it in the subclass __ init __? Example code to reproduce the issue:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestCaseSubClass(TestCase):

    def __init__(self, param, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Just use whatever is in TestCase's init + our stuff
        self.thing = param
        print(self.thing)


class TestClass(TestCaseSubClass(param='bdfbdfb')):

        def test_stuff(self):
            print('test stuff here')
```

Or with just raw python, no import, why cant I do this? (same error)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, athing='thing'):
        self.thing = athing
        print(self.thing)

class AB(A):
    def __init__(self, param, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.param= param
        print(self.param)


class ABC(AB(param='thh')):
    pass

ABCinstance = ABC()
```

Comment: I don't think that code should give that error. The way you wrote it (syntax error notwithstanding) should _not_ pass `param` on to the parent's `__init__`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe it's because of what I am subclassing? unittest.TestCase in this case. Here is a working example: https://onlinegdb.com/rJfgN183X

Comment: This is how you are supposed to use TestCase: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example
The only thing I am doing is expanding upon TestCase with my own SubClass

Comment: What do you expect `AB(param='thh')`, a class instance, to do inside a class definition?

Comment: OHHHHH that's it! I thought you had to specify required AB params when I defined ABC subclass. I guess you don't have to. You send AB params when instantiating an ABC class. Make an answer that was it.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess this part of the question was mostly a misunderstanding :) I don't think future readers with the same issue would find this question. Whereas the answer you have is a good answer to something which _could_ have been what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting this question as "how can I provide a default parameter to a subclass without defining an `__init__` for it?". One possible way is to define the default value as a class attribute, which you access in the parent class' `__init__`:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestCaseSubClass(TestCase):
    _default_param = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        param = kwargs.pop("param", self._default_param)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Just use whatever is in TestCase's init + our stuff
        self.thing = param

class TestClass(TestCaseSubClass):
    _default_param = "bdfbdfb"
    def test_stuff(self):
        print('test stuff here')

x = TestClass()
print(x.thing) #"bdfbdfb"
y = TestClass(param="foo")
print(y.thing) #"foo"
```

This approach doesn't *quite* match the argument format in your question, since now `param` is a keyword-only argument, rather than a named positional argument. The principal practical difference is that you can't supply an argument for `param` unless you refer to it by name: `z = TestClass("foo")` won't do it, for example.

---

Based on the edits and comments to this question, another possible interpretation may be "How can I provide a parameter to a subclass that gets passed to the parent class, by any means necessary?", which has no requirement regarding default values. If you're willing to make `param` a *mandatory* parameter, then you simply need to pass the value in when creating a TestClass instance:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestCaseSubClass(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, param, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Just use whatever is in TestCase's init + our stuff
        self.thing = param

class TestClass(TestCaseSubClass):
    def test_stuff(self):
        print('test stuff here')

x = TestClass("bdfbdfb")
print(x.thing) #"bdfbdfb"
```